# Browsers don't respond to external link

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome, firefox, browser

When I click hyperlinks in some softs (Adobe Reader, unity3d, FileZilla, shadowsocksR, eve launcher, etc), the browsers don't respond at all.

The browsers (Firefox, Chrome and IE) work normally by themselves. And whichever is chosen to be default, the problem maintains.

Some softs do call on the browsers successfully: Explorer, Word, QQ (a chatting soft), a eye-protecting small application.

If I reboot Windows in Safe Mode with web support, the problem is gone,
but it comes back in normal mode.

Does this mean, the differences in authorities or APIs of these softs make them able or unable to open URL in default browsers?

For most softs that failed, just nothing happened after the click. But for FileZilla and ShadowsockR, I got some error messages:

---

FileZilla error messages:
[image: filezilla error message1]

[image: filezilla error message2]

The log for FileZilla2 (same as second error message):

```
20:40:04: Failed to open URL "https://offers.filezilla-project.org/redirect.php?c=seed4me&s=u" in default browser. (error -2147221003: 找不到应用程序)
20:40:04: Could not launch the default browser with url 'https://offers.filezilla-project.org/redirect.php?c=seed4me&s=u' !
20:41:41: Failed to open URL "https://filezilla-project.org/" in default browser. (error -2147221003: 找不到应用程序)
20:41:41: Could not launch the default browser with url 'https://filezilla-project.org/' !
20:41:52: Failed to open URL "https://filezilla-project.org/sponsored_updates.php" in default browser. (error -2147221003: 找不到应用程序)
20:41:52: Could not launch the default browser with url 'https://filezilla-project.org/sponsored_updates.php' !
```

---

ShadowsocksR error log:
[image: ShadowsocksR error log]:

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): 找不到应用程序
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Shadowsocks.View.MenuViewController.AboutItem_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem.MenuItemData.Execute()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Command.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon.WndProc(Message& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1590.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
ShadowsocksR
    Assembly Version: 4.7.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.7.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Jules%20Liu/Downloads/ShadowsocksR-4.7.0-win/ShadowsocksR-dotnet4.0.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1590.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1590.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1590.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1590.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1590.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1590.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```